# Enterprise architect: Automation scripting: Show created ports on element component in diagram

Tags: scripting, automation, enterprise-architect, ports

I am writing a Python script to create diagrams,elements in Enterprise Architect. I have created a port and attached it to the element but now i Need this port be visible on the element in the diagram view. I searched the available classes and packages in the documentation but couldn't find any function for element/port visability.

NB: I don't Need to do it from the program, i Need a scripting function, the scripting language is not an issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to locate the element. Ports and other embedded elements are child elements. So look into `parent.elements` to retrieve the right element.

Now placing it in a diagram is the same as with its parent. You create a `diagramObject` and place it at the right location on the border of the parent element. Something like this:

```
dia_obj = diagram.DiagramObjects.AddNew ("l=10;r=110;t=-20;b=-80", "");
dia_obj.ElementID = element.ElementID;
dia_obj.Update ();
Repository.ReloadDiagram (diagram.DiagramID);
```

NB: In V10 (up to build 1006) the embedded element is not placed correctly but EA places it somewhere at the side of the embedding class. This bug has been fixed with V11 (build 1103).

Comment: Thanks that worked, however i tried to do the same for Interfaces attached to ports but it failed. Shouldn't it be using the same procedure, since Interface is an element as well? I have a port assigned to a provided Interface and i Need the Interface visible as well on the diagram.

Comment: I thought that too, but a quick test did not succeed. I'll try later the evening what might be the cause.

Comment: I just tested it. The update for adding the iface diagram object does not respond true. I regard this a bug. Probably you are the first trying (or asking for) that. Please send a bug report: http://sparxsystems.com/support/forms/bug_report.html

Comment: Yaah that was my issue as well the update method did not work. Well, thats quite interesting that no one had found that bug before :). Anyways will raise a bug shortly. And thank you very much for the help, as well as for the writing the book about scripting it helped me a lot starting with Enterprise Architect, although i only have the draft version :D

Comment: @uffe What's the reason for removing my remark about the source of the citation?